# I see less than half of the number of push notification sent on firebase dashboard than number we actual send daily using pyfcm library

Tags: python-3.x, django, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-analytics-firebase, pyfcm

We send more than 500k push notifications daily but only 150k messages sent on that day shown in Firebase dashboard.

I want to know why firebase dashboard analytics not giving correct number for messages sent daily and how can i fix this issue